# Overbrace not aligning with itself

Tags: math-mode, align, typography, overbrace, alignment

Why aren't my overbraces displaying correctly?

The code for this segment is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{align*}
  g^{(e)}(x) &= \overbrace{(1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots)}^{\text{red}}\overbrace{(1 + \frac{x}{1} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots)}^{\text{green}}\overbrace{(1 + \frac{x}{1} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots)}^{\text{white}}\\
  ...
\end{align*}
...
\end{document}
```

And it gets typeset like in the image below.
[image: Misaligned overbrace]

I'm honestly not sure what packages are required to build this bit of code (there's a lot more stuff in the document, as you might imagine) so I left all of them in there—maybe there's a conflict between them?

Comment: not relevant to question, but if you're using `amsart`, `amsmath` and `amsfonts` are already loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is the load order of [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and [`mathabx`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathabx). Use this order:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[
  g^{(e)}(x) = \overbrace{\bigl( 1 + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \tfrac{x^4}{4!} + \dots \bigr)}^{\text{red}}
    \overbrace{\bigl( 1 + \tfrac{x}{1} + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dots \bigr)}^{\text{green}}
    \overbrace{\bigl( 1 + \tfrac{x}{1} + \tfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dots \bigr)}^{\text{white}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I definitely wouldn't have thought that the _order_ of package loading would matter. Care to shed some light on the details?

Comment: @alan: General details: Some packages take care to see what other packages have been loaded and/or load their macros at different times (not just all at package load/`\usepackage` using `\AtBeginDocument`, say). However, in general, there are too may combinations of load orders to consider and therefore the onus rests with the end-user. [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is a typical example of a package that should typically be [loaded last](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764), because it makes changes to many fundamental document elements.